# Changing select sections of text to different colors in a tkinter text box?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, tags

First I would like to say I am not looking to take spacific words and change all words related to that tag. I am trying to do something akin to highlighting text in word and just changing the text color.

I have a program that will output the string stored in a dictionary by calling the key. I want to change sections of text color within the string but not necessarily all the iterations of that text.

I don't think tagging words would do the job for me as it would take a lot of time to define all the different words I want to change the color of and I do not want all words to be changed.
If it is possible to highlight the words and click a button to color the text as well as when I save the text to the library the text retains its color given. That is more along the lines of what I am trying to do.

Further more if it is possible to create some kind of rule that looks for a set of characters and then takes everything inside those characters and changes the color.

Could I write something that would read the data inside the dictionary and look for an identifier lets call it `clrGr*` and then look for a closing identifier, lets call it `clrGr**` and then any text or string inside the identifiers would have been changed to green. by calling a tag or something similar.

```
clrGr* Just random string of text between the identifiers clrGr**
```

What I get currently only lets me change all the color of the text.
[image]

Now what I want to do is have something like the following display in my tkinter text box.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Applying tags via regular expression

The text widget supports finding ranges of text specified by a regular expression.

Note: the expression must follow [tcl regular expression syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), which has some slight differences from python regular expressions.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text.tag_configure("highlight", foreground="green")

text.insert("1.0", '''
blah blah
blah clrGr* Just random string of text between the identifiers clrGr** blah
blah blah
''')

# this just highlights the first match, but you can put this code
# in a loop to highlight the whole file
char_count = tk.IntVar()
index = text.search(r'(?:clrGr\*).*(?:clrGr\*\*)', "1.0", "end", count=char_count, regexp=True)

# we have to adjust the character indexes to skip over the identifiers
if index != "":
    start = "%s + 6 chars" % index
    end = "%s + %d chars" % (index, char_count.get()-7)
    text.tag_add("highlight", start, end)

root.mainloop()
```

### Saving the color information

You can, however, call the `dump` method on a text widget to get a list of tuples that describe the content of the text widget. You can use this information to either write directly to a file (in a format that only your app will understand), or to convert the data to a known format.

The best description of what the `dump` method returns is described in the tcl/tk man pages: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M108

Comment: @`Bryan Oalkey` all this looks interesting. I will look into it more when I get back to work tomorrow and see what I can come up with based on the info you provided. I will post back on here once I have made some progress.

Comment: @ `Bryan Oalkey` So I got the tag thing working I was wondering if there is a way tag the text without having the tags be visible. Or if I could removed the tags after the highlight happens.

Comment: @BaconTech: If you don't configure the tags with any attributes, they won't be visible.

Comment: Would that erase everything inside the tag also? I just want to remove the identifiers themselves.

Comment: @BaconTech: The easiest way to answer questions like that is to simply try it and see.

Comment: I am still having problems with creating a tag that is not seen by the user. I have been able to target words as I need to but so far not able to create tags that are not visible. For now what I need to do here is good to go. I have avoided so far needing to store my text highlighted as I have a code that will highlight as the string is displayed every time.

Comment: @BaconTech: Here's how to create a tag that is invisible: `text.tag_add("this_is_invisible", start, end)`. Set `start` and `end` to whatever you want. There's literally nothing else you must do. Though, I'm not sure I see the point of adding invisible tags.

Comment: I don't want the text to be inviable. Just the tags around the text

Comment: When you say "just the tags around the text", are you referring to text widget tags, or strings in your data like "clrGr" and "clrGr*"?

Comment: So the Idea I had was when I am typing the notes I could type some kind of identifier around the stuff I wanted to highlight such as "clrGr". Once the note was saved the next time the note was brought up in my text box the code would look for the tags then highlight everything inside the tag then remove the tag so its not part of the visible text. Let me know if this makes no sense lol.

Comment: @BaconTech: ok. This answer has almost everything you need to accomplish this. The one missing piece is that you can configure the `elide` option of a tag so that any text with that tag will be invisible. So, create a text widget tag named "hidden" (`text.tag_configure("hidden", elide=True`) and then use the technique in this answer to add that text tag to every one of your "tags" (eg: search for 'ClrGr*' and add the tag "hidden" to it)

Comment: I did manage to get the `elide` option working. I did not know if there was a easy way to tell search statement to look for both `<<` tag and `>>` tag. So I just created a for loop and applied  a list of all the tags I wanted to removed after the highlighting was complete. Thanks for all the help. With all the above information I am now able to create any tag I wish and target any word for highlighting as well as remove said tags after the highlighting is done. The only issue I can see at this point is when I update the notes to my library the tags will be gone for the next run.